# SqLite database won't close when in unicode and PRAGMA journal_mode is set

Tags: c, unicode, sqlite

My windows application (written in C) uses SQLite (using the embedded amalgamated source) for storing offline data, and have had no problems with it in a multibyte character set build.  I'm now converting the codebase to Unicode.  SQLite is quite happily running with the Unicode build, creating SQLite databases in UTF-16LE encoding.

I've come across one very odd thing, though.  If I run the query `PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE` (actually, setting it to ANY of the allowed values, including `OFF`, does the same thing), everything runs fine until the code closes the database, at which point the call to `sqlite3_close()` returns `SQLITE_BUSY`, with the error `"unable to close due to unfinalised statements"`.

This happens even if the only query I run on the database is that single pragma command!  I can run other pragmas fine (e.g. `"PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL"`) and all my SQL queries, and the database will close quite happily; it's just this `journal_mode` pragma that's causing this odd behaviour, and ONLY in the Unicode build of the code - the multibyte build doesn't show this problem.  This happens whether the database exists already [in UTF-16LE mode], or whether it creates it on first opening.

Any ideas what could be wrong?  I'm using SQLite build v3.7.11.

Comment: One other note: Technically the pragma call isn't the only query I run: I also run the call `PRAGMA quick_check(1)` when I first open/create the DB.

Comment: Slightly confused, `journal_mode` does not appear to have `NORMAL` as one of its allowed values

Comment: Whoops, I meant "DELETE" - i.e. the default.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in the end.  Was in my own wrapper code.  As sqlite has no unicode equivalent call for `sqlite3_exec()`, I had let the unicode version drop through to my code that does prepare/step/finalize (for when the caller wants data back from an SQL query), but for some reason setting the journal_mode pragma causes SqLite to return some data, which it doesn't for the other pragmas I set - thus there was an unfinalised stmt for just this pragma.

For future reference, if you get SQLITE_BUSY when closing, you can call `sqlite3_next_stmt()` to get the [next] unfinalised statement, then `sqlite3_sql()` to get it to tell you the prepared SQL statement associated with it.  Very useful!